# Java start program on user login (platform-wide)

Tags: java, cross-platform, startup, startupscript

Across linux, MAC, and Windows, is there any way to make a Java program startup on login? I know on windows their would just need to be a shortcut to the jar file in the user's startup folder. But for linux and MAC what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no cross-platform method of starting a program at login or boot, but you can configure each individually.

**Windows** - Put the program in your user's startup folder in or use a scheduled task, both detailed here: [[Instructions]](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html)

**Mac** - Configure through system preferences: [[Instructions]](http://www.apple.com/findouthow/mac/#appstartup)

**Linux** - Configure `~/.bashrc` to start on login or use `/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit` to start on boot.